# Not in Cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using Cakephp2.3.

I have two conditions in my code:

```
$resnew=$this->AdmissionEnquiry->find('all',array('conditions'=>array("not" => array ( "AdmissionEnquiry.phone_no" => ''),array("not"=>array('AdmissionEnquiry.is_notified'=>1)))));
```

This is not working fine. I want to use not for two fields.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this

Thanks!

Comment: Where are the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way, a *single* 'not' key, containing multiple arrays, 1 per field;

```
$resnew = $this->AdmissionEnquiry->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            "not" => array ( 
                array("AdmissionEnquiry.phone_no" => ''),
                array('AdmissionEnquiry.is_notified' => 1),
            )
        )
    )
);
```